# How to find values in range with respect to next column value and these value should within Time range?

Tags: excel, vba

| Time | Machine |
| --- | --- |
| 03:03:10 | A |
| 03:45:10 | A |
| 03:03:11 | A |
| 03:45:10 | B |
| 03:03:10 | B |
| 03:03:10 | B |
| 03:03:10 | C |
| 03:45:10 | C |
| 03:03:10 | C |

I have two things:
2) when I select Machine (A) then he will try to find the time should be between 03:00:00 and 03:08:00 if yes in cell A should have ("COMPLETED") then paste these timings in cell B like (03:03:10, 03:03:10) with commas in between. Else NOT FOUND.

I have the following code but without time range condition:
`search_rep = Sheets("MAIN").Range("A3").Value Set search_range = Sheets("Raw data2").Range("A1:B50") For Each cell In search_range.Cells If cell.Value = search_rep Then Sheets("MAIN").Range("C3") = "COMPLETED" result = result & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & ", " result = Left(result, Len(result)) Sheets("MAIN").Range("D3").Value = result End If Next cell If Sheets("MAIN").Range("D3").Value = ("") Then Sheets("MAIN").Range("C3") = "NOT FOUND" End If`
I have two things:
2) when I select Machine (A) then he will try to find the time should be between 03:00:00 and 03:08:00 if yes in cell A should have ("COMPLETED") then paste these timings in cell B like (03:03:10, 03:03:10) with commas in between. Else NOT FOUND.

Comment: Please modify your post to format the code for better readability. Currently, all the code is on a single line.